# How to implement setOnItemClickListener on ListView while accessing listview row(Accessing individual Row)?

Tags: android

I am able to access the individual row of listview.
But listview.setOnItemClickListener() method is not working.

Actually on listview row there is button I can access that also I'm able to set ClickListener on it.It's Working.

But the problem is listview.setOnItemClickListener() method is not responding.Is it possible
to have that both functionality.Thanks in Advance,Sorry for My english.

This is my getView

```
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i("Position", "" + position);
            view = convertView;

            if (view == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                view = inflater.inflate(row, null);
                holder = new AttractionViewHolder();
                holder.tvName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.attName);
                holder.add = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.attAdd);
                holder.tvdetails = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.attDetails);
                holder.attImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.attImage);
                holder.attPbar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.attProgress);
                holder.ratingBar = (RatingBar) view.findViewById(R.id.attRating);
                view.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (AttractionViewHolder) view.getTag();
            }
            placeObject = placeList.get(position);

            name = placeObject.getName();
            holder.tvName.setText(name);

            holder.attPbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            holder.attImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.img1);
            holder.ratingBar.setRating(Float.parseFloat(Integer
                    .toString(placeObject.getStar())));
            holder.tvdetails.setTag(position);
            holder.add.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.add);
            holder.add.setTag(position);

            holder.add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    String id[] = new String[placeList.size()];
                    String name[] = new String[placeList.size()];
                    Object o = v.getTag();
                    int pos = Integer.parseInt(o.toString());
                    Log.i("Pos", "" + pos);
                    if (position == pos) {
                        placeObject = placeList.get(position);
                        if (id.length > i) {
                            id[i] = placeObject.getId();
                            name[i] = placeObject.getName();
                            i++;
                        }    

                    }
                }



            });

            holder.tvdetails.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Object o = v.getTag();
                    int pos = Integer.parseInt(o.toString());

                    if (pos == position) {
                        Log.i("Click","You Clicked");
                    }
                }
            });



            return view;
        }
        public class AttractionViewHolder {

            public TextView tvName, tvdetails;
            private ImageView attImage;
            private ProgressBar attPbar;
            private Button add;
            RatingBar ratingBar;



}
```

Comment: Have you created a customized list view?

Comment: u need to create holder for the listItems

Comment: Yes but where to create holder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for each Button add this to layout:

```
android:focusable="false"
```

and then in getView find each Button and then assign it the appropriate click listener.

Comment: Thanks That work's.but how can I know which row's button is clicked?

Comment: post your getView till i tell you

Comment: okay you have already implemented it, the row button of your array at "position" is clicked. you can access the data of that row by this list.get(position);

Comment: Thats okay but how to get that data inn listview.setOnclickListener()method

Comment: try this mListView.getAdapter().getItem(position); and in your getview adapter adapter.getItem(position); and in your listener for each button adaptername.this..getItem(arg0);

Comment: Could you elaborate your answer

Comment: "how can I know which row's button is clicked?" explain exactly what you want to do?

Comment: On each row there is button when I click on that button can i know which row's button is clicked or simply the row number

Comment: you write your code in the listener of each button. you know your button are not you? look at the variable name of different button you found and different listener you wrote: holder.tvdetails , holder.add and in order to find which row look at the position

Comment: I know all the views and the click listeners are working too. But how can I know that holder.add is clicked of which row of listview.

Comment: look at (int position) that getView passes to you.

Comment: but that passes in my custom adapter class.Can i get that in my main class where I am setting custom adapter to my listview and itemclicklistener on listview

Comment: what do you want to do when the button clicked

Comment: hey look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25187400/updating-textview-on-activity-once-data-in-adapter-class-is-changed/25187612#25187612

Comment: I want to store that row

Comment: if you want to store in memory or variable or sharedprefences or database use the idea of the link i passed to you, if you want add it to the list create new object of your list content object add it and call notifydatasetchange. if you search more you could find better solutions because i really do not know what "i want to store it" means

Comment: what has worked? can you tell me because i want to know your chosen solution, thank you

Comment: I take arraylist in adapter class.I added objects(holder.add clicked event) in that list and through getter setter I got that list of objects

Answer (score 0):

`android:focusable="false"` for `Button`.

In this case you ListView will fire onItemClick action to listener, and the Button will also work when it clicked.