# Android Imageview in Listview onClick change image doesn't work properly

Tags: java, android, android-listview, imageview, android-arrayadapter

I have a ListView and in every single ListviewItem there is an ImageView with a little star (for marking it as favourite). Therefore I put an OnClickListener to the ImageView on every item in the custom ArrayAdapter.

```
imgStar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imgStar.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
            Bitmap bitmap2 = ((BitmapDrawable)(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_not_important))).getBitmap();

            if(bitmap != bitmap2) {
                    imgStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_not_important);
            } else {
                    imgStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_important);
            }
        }
    });
```

The problem: When I get some items and click for example on the star of the first item, the image changes as it should but a few items lower the image changes too o.O
I tested it with some code: The thing that won't get into my head is it is only changing the image (on the other item below), code that would be executed in the onclick is only executed for the item I really click not for the one where the image changes too.

Why does the image of a random other item in the list change also? I hope someone can help me.

Custom Adapter Constructore Code

```
public LinkArrayAdapter(Context con, int textViewResourceId) {
    super(con, textViewResourceId);
    context = con;

}
```

Comment: Is this code inside custom adapter ?

Comment: Yes, this code is in the custom adapter (in the getView event) which is added to the listview

Comment: you need a random changing image while you click on a  star image .right?

Comment: you need to store position of clicked position in array and check item position is inside array or not.

Comment: No thats exactly NOT what I want :D I want to change the image only in the imageview where I really clicked, not in an imageview of an item below where I never clicked

Comment: Can you give me an example @Imtiyaz

Comment: Check the code in this question. Although purpose is different, Listener is applied item wise http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25187400/updating-textview-on-activity-once-data-in-adapter-class-is-changed

Comment: @Phil have you use any model class or bean clsss for setting data on adapter?. like List<MyModel> list; something.

Comment: yes, `private List<OneComment> data = new ArrayList<OneComment>();`

Comment: Where you define `List<OneComment> data`?

Comment: global at the begin of the adapter class

Comment: now add boolean named isStar (name does not metter) in OneComment.

Comment: okay and what to do with this boolean? I mean I need to set it to true/false somewhere, but where?

Comment: Please show your adapter, its hard to tell without it

Comment: @Phil now check updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you can't change the image of items in the `onClick` then leave it and hope it will be updated on every item on the list. Because `onClick` get called in different time than `getView`. So you must set item images outside of `onClick` but in the `getView` so every time that `getView` called for a specific item it will set the appropriate image for that item.

Define a boolean array in your CustomAdapter class as:

```
private boolean[] stars;
```

Then in constructor method of your class, initialize it as:

```
this.stars = new boolean[items.size()];
```

In the `onClick` method:

```
// **Edited to apply image update at click**
stars[position] = !stars[position];
notifyDataSetInvalidated();
```

At last in the `getView()` method of custom adapter
(ensure this code **is not** in any other inner blocks):

```
if (stars[position])
  imgStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_important);
else
  imgStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_not_important);
```

Comment: in the constructor I have no `items` variable

Comment: So what type of data you passed to adapter to show and what's that variable name in the adapter class?

Comment: I pass it through the class "OneComment" and the data are different strings. In OneComment constructor I set it like `this.link = link` and in my adapter I call `OneComment comment = getItem(position)` and then I can use the data like `comment.link` for the link e.g.

Comment: Please add your custom adapter constructor code in your question

Comment: Sorry, i can't guess where is your data array. but it must be an array or ArrayList because you have a list-view so you have a list of data and it has a specified size. you must set the "stars" boolean-array size to that size.

Comment: Ok understood it. I add the items on the fly, that's why I can't set the size in the constructor. I made an counter which is += 1 for every add and sets the size of the boolean array. But there is still the same problem: I click the star of the first item, it changes, but the star of another item changes too.

Comment: I edited the answer. sorry, you must move that `if` statement out of `onClick` method. Because the adapter must set image for every item based on stars array...

Comment: Finally it's working! :) But it's very very slow, it takes much time until the star is updatet, do you know why?

Comment: Maybe it's because of the image is not updated until `getView()` is called on that item and it is called when you scroll the list... You can try to call `notifyDataSetInvalidated();` in the `onClick`

Comment: Yes, now it's much faster, not instant but acceptable :) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
    private int  selectedPositions ;

    // /... your code.
            convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    OneComment mComment = mlist.get(position);
                    mComment.isStart = !mComment.isStart;
                    if(mComment.isStar){
//set star image
} else{
do not set star image}

                }
            });
```

Comment: I click on the star of the first item, it gets added, but on the 7th item it gets added too, same problem as before :/

Comment: you want only one item with start from entire list right?

Comment: exactly, the item with the star should be exact that item where i clicked on that imageview for the star (I think it's nearly similar to the gmail app for marking an email as favorite)

Comment: Sorry, this is stil not working. It always sets another star which I never clicked :( Edit: got a working solution now (see above), but still gave you upvote for your ideas and help! :) thank you

Answer (score 0):

@semsamot's answer works, however
`notifyDataSetInvalidated()` causes the List to reload and goes to the first item.
Use `notifyDataSetChanged()` instead.