# ListView change position of his element when scroll down or up android

Tags: listview, android-adapter, simpleadapter

I have simple adapter and set to him two values name and email.After that use adapter in list to show name and email.My problem comes when i scroll down list , and if i check first value and scroll down the value that i checked change his possition.I think the problem comes from adapter but i dont know how to resolved it.

```
// /simple adapter, with his help we can set email and name
        // to list view and visual them
        final SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, list,
                R.layout.custom_row_view, new String[] { "name", "email" },
                new int[] { R.id.listItem, R.id.listSubItem });



Button buttonPickContact = (Button) findViewById(R.id.contactact_us_btn);
    buttonPickContact.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // clear list every time when pick contact button is clicked
            list.clear();
            populateList();
            // set email and name to listview with help of adapter
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            // set multiple choise to listview
            listview.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

            listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> p_arg0, View p_arg1,
                        int p_arg2, long p_arg3) {
                    // if some of the items in list view is clicked
                    // set checked true
                    CheckedTextView checkText = (CheckedTextView) p_arg1
                            .findViewById(R.id.listItem);
                    // if clicked item from list view is not checked
                    // set checked true to item
                    checkText.setChecked(!checkText.isChecked());

                }

            });

        }
    });



// populate(add email and names) from contact list in phone to listview
    private void populateList() {

        ContactsProvider cpro = new ContactsProvider(getApplicationContext());
        List<Contact> contacts = cpro.getContacts();
        // with this loop get emails and names
        // put them in map and after that
        // put map in listview
        for (Contact cnt : contacts) {
            // add all contacts in map
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            // then put email and name of contacts in map
            map.put("name", cnt.name);
            map.put("email", cnt.email);

            list.add(map);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `ListView` you shouldn't set property of an item in the `onClick` method because of recycling system of `ListView`. Instead you must set it in `getView` method of `Adapter`.
So you must create a custom adapter.
Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25403471/3922482