# After Click on toolbar, CountDownTimer value is not showing in Text View

Tags: android, textview, countdowntimer

This is my timer Code in which first time value is showing but after Click on toolbar text view is not Showing and Log is Showing its correct value.

```
countDownTimmer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.countDownTimmer);     
timmermMin = getIntent().getStringExtra("timmermMin");


 yourCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(Integer.parseInt(timmermMin) * 60000, 1000) {
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {       
                     seconds = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                    hour = seconds / 3600;
                    minutes = (seconds % 3600) / 60;
                    seconds = seconds % 60;
                    countDownTimmer.setText("TIME : " + String.format("%02d", hour) + ":" + String.format("%02d", minutes)
                            + ":" + String.format("%02d", seconds));

                    Log.e("Time",+hour + " " + minutes + " " + seconds + " ");
                    Log.e("millisUntilFinished", String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished));
                    milliSecondRemaining = String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished);

                }

                public void onFinish() {
                  countDownTimmer.setText("Time Up!");

                }
            }.start();
```

And My tool bar back Press code is :

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                // todo: goto back activity from here
                Intent intent = new Intent(TestSubjectActivity.this, TestSubjectActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.putExtra("timmermMin",milliSecondRemaining);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: you need to do every UI changes on UI thread.....let me know if you wanted any description

Comment: yes sure..I want a description

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 notifyPropertyChanged()
```

method if it doesnt help you probably need to do [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25187400/updating-textview-on-activity-once-data-in-adapter-class-is-changed)

Comment: where we have to put this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
 yourCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(Integer.parseInt(timmermMin) * 60000, 1000) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {       
                 seconds = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                hour = seconds / 3600;
                minutes = (seconds % 3600) / 60;
                seconds = seconds % 60;
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                    countDownTimmer.setText("TIME : " + String.format("%02d", hour) + ":" + String.format("%02d", minutes)
            + ":" + String.format("%02d", seconds));
                    }
                });

                Log.e("Time",+hour + " " + minutes + " " + seconds + " ");
                Log.e("millisUntilFinished", String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished));
                milliSecondRemaining = String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished);

            }

            public void onFinish() {
              countDownTimmer.setText("Time Up!");

            }
        }.start();
```

Comment: will you please help to solve this problem @Mohammad Zarei